# What is the best way to make a list that you can add to non indexed locations

Tags: java, list, arraylist

If you try

```
    List<Boolean> alist = new ArrayList<Boolean>();

    alist.add(5, true);
```

You get an error, because you cant add to an index that is not in the list. What do i use in order to be able to write:

```
any.add(73, true)

if any.get(52) {
  // Do something
}
```

Only if the list has stored something in 73, it will be true, otherwise false.

Comment: I don't get your question. What exactly do you want?

Comment: what about hashmap http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Use a HashMap. Map your indexes with the appropriate boolean values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not actually interested in the boolean value, and you just want to check if the number has been entered at all. If that's the case, a HashSet will likely be a better choice than a HashMap:

```
HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

hashSet.add(4);
hashSet.add(100843);
hashSet.add(91);

System.out.println(hashSet.contains(4)); //true
System.out.println(hashSet.contains(10)); //false
```

Comment: Nice observation! +1. Also note that `= new HashSet<Integer>` is only neccessary on Java 6 and lower, Java 7 and higher can infer the type arguments, so you can use diamond notation `HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();`.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I just wrote this down without checking that it would actually run.

Comment: I also realized that i could use an integer list in the same way with .contains, but maybe a hashset is faster, if the list is searched with a line search.

Comment: If you're just adding integers and then checking that they're in the set, a HashSet is almost certainly faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Custom HashMap. Map your indexes with the appropriate boolean values using that.

Here's an example of such custom hash map:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class IndexMap extends HashMap<Integer, Boolean>
{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 7891095847767899453L;

  @Override
  public Boolean get(Object key)
  {
    if (containsKey(key))
      return super.get(key);
    return false;
  }
}
```

And here's a demonstration of such map:

```
public class Demo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    IndexMap map = new IndexMap();

    map.put(5, true);
    map.put(73, true);

    System.out.println(map.get(73)); // Prints true.
    System.out.println(map.get(52)); // Prints false.
  }
}
```

Comment: So what would `map.get(52);` return? This is not what OP want.

Comment: Well as you know, map.get(52) will return null, which can be checked, and converted to false using a helper method. I'll make appropriate changes to my answer soon.

Comment: It is not preferred in general to extend java library classes, so I would not recommend this.

Comment: All I did was create a wrapper for the HashMap so that it can be used in this particular situation in an easy way. I see no issues in extending predefined Java Library classes as well, to suit the situation's needs. If you can show me someplace which highly recommends (with logical reasoning) not to extend Java library classes, then I'll be much obliged.

Answer (score 0):

List maintain the ordering of the element, so you can't add the element at any specific order if the size of the list is less than that particular index.

i.e

```
element @ particular index addition <= list size
```

So you can move to Map and then the index will be the index of the element and value as boolean i.e

```
Map<Integer,Boolean>
```